# HQL - find entity where property x is highest

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Can HQL queries do this?

"get the UserEntity where the property creationTimestamp is the most recent of all UserEntities".

Essentially a query to return the "newest user" in our program where each UserEntity has a field mapped to a timestamp column in our database.

Comment: Without using setMaxResults would be best.

Comment: so you want to return more than one user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HQL query to list the users from newest first is:

```
from UserEntities
order by creationTimestamp desc
```

Use [**`setMaxResults`**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29) to limit the result set to just one user.

Answer (score 7):

Querying for the highest creationTimestamp would look like this:

```
from UserEntity where creationTimestamp = max(creationTimestamp)
```

If you want to return only a single instance and ignore other results that have the same (highest) value on that property, you can use `query.uniqueResult()`.

See [Chapter 14. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) for further reference.

Comment: +1 for pointing out select is not needed. But I am wondering, could your query in theory return more than one user in some situations?

Comment: That's correct! It can return more than one but the question was to find where a property is the highest... which item do you expect when multiple have the highest value on that property?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [`HQL order-by`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-ordering) clause?